# Looking for an editor that supports editor-based notes/comments

Tags: editors, comments, notes

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I'm currently looking for a suitable LaTeX editor. Right now I'm using Texmaker, which seems fine, but I'm really missing the possibility to write editor-based notes as opposed to only comments within the text itself.

Overleaf supports the type of notes that I'd like to use, but I'd prefer not to write everything online. Are there any other editors that support these types of editor-notes?

Here's a screenshot of one of these comments/notes in Overleaf:
[image]

Comment: most (all?) locally installed tex editors only have the tex file no hidden data for each document so whatever the display within the editor the data would need to be stored in the tex file (as comments or something)

Comment: I find comments introduced with `%` so convenient that I haven’t tested this, but you may want to look at [annotate](https://github.com/bastibe/annotate.el) for Emacs.